# In Linux, Java uses Rxtx serial port to appear abnormal, but Windows is work

Tags: java

In Linux, Java uses Rxtx serial port to appear abnormal, but Windows works.
when i click 'start' button, jvm error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f83aa558d9d, pid=21887, tid=0x00007f83aa316700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6d9d]  read_byte_array+0x3d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/Workspaces/MyEclipse 2017/telegram/hs_err_pid21887.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: What is the question?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp_

Comment: Time will solve everything,this problem was solved after I updated the latest version,but now,a new problem occurd,when i close serialport(  API:serialport.close();  ), the  program always stuck ...do you have a solution?